# delete entry from sqlite data base in android application. where to get the that row id to pass it ot delete function

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, delete-row

After going through many posts I am posting my query. Not able to get proper resolution for my problem.

I am using sqlite and inserting some data (name, info etc..)

Now I get the all rows and show in list view.

Now user selects a one list entry for deletion, I have to call db.delete with id which is rowid of that particular record.

How will get the record id?

When user selects from list view I have position number which is index to the list. But not the database row id where that entry resides.

Do i have to save all ids returned when I call db.insert(table, data) when rows are created?

all examples show the implementation like

```
    public void deleteRow(long id) {

    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });

    }
```

where should i get id from?

Comment: You'll just have to keep track of which row in the list is which. You're getting the data from the database anyway

Comment: When you get the db content you can save the row Id in you object

Comment: see: onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long **id**) onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long **id**) and onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long **id**) do you see that in all cases you have position and id ?

Answer (score 0):

For setup a list view you have create an Adapter, right?

The adapter hold your entries and create the views.

Ask your adapter which item is on position x.

The BaseAdapter implement a getItemId method.

```
public long getItemId(int position) {

    // Example for List<Object>
    return mItems.get(position).getId();

}
```

You can simple call `adapter.getItemId(x);` or use `OnItemClickListener` that give the ID.

For more informations loot at the android developer pages.

SimpleAdapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html

ArrayAdapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

BaseAdapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

I hope it helps.

**Updated**:

Use `getItemId(int)` instead of `getItem(int)`, thanks to @pskink

Comment: what `getId` do you mean ?

Comment: Yes I use list view with Adapter and I am aware that I get the position of the list entry. Say user long pressed on position 2, I have to delete details represented by that position. But I cannot use position number pass to db.delete to delete record ..right? because row id could be different when inserting this entry to database.
So getId() of my object should store the return value of db.insert() call? in order to use it for deletion?

Comment: The `getId()` is from the record object. I think he create a object from the database record and save the data (with ID) in that.

Comment: @Fabi755 So my object should setId() with return value of db.insert() call ? And the same should use it further with getId()?.

Comment: @Sudarshansridhar `"When user selects from list view I have position number which is index to the list."` you also have an **ID**, not only position

Comment: Yes that's right. Store the database ID in your created object and return it in example on `getId()`.

Comment: no need for `getId`, see `onItemLongClick`(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long **id**) and `onItemSelected`(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long **id**)

Comment: @pskink You're right, this solution is easier, but the id come from the adapter too. I have update my answer for using the `getItemId()` method.