# Filling the list

Tags: android, list, sqlite

In the below code I get data from database and add them to the court class, finally add the court class to the  courtList. 
But the final courtList's items are the same . All the data are the last data in the database. 
How can I solve it?   Where is my mistake?

Thank's

```
public List<Court> getListOfCourt(){

    List<Court> courtList;

    Court court= new Court();
    String[] col= new String[]{
            CourtTable.OFFICE_FILE_CODE,
            CourtTable.CLIENT_ID,
            CourtTable.COURT_DATE
    };

    SQLiteDatabase sd= getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur= sd.query(CourtTable.TABLE_NAME, col, null, null, null, null,null);

    courtList = new ArrayList<Court>() ;

    if(cur!=null && cur.getCount()>0){
        cur.moveToFirst();
        do{
            court.setOfficeFileCode(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(CourtTable.OFFICE_FILE_CODE)));
            court.setClientId(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(CourtTable.CLIENT_ID)));
            court.setCourtDate(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CourtTable.COURT_DATE)));

            courtList.add(court);
        }
        while(cur.moveToNext());
    }
    return courtList;
}
```

Comment: your mistake is that you are not using `[Simple]CursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Put this line " Court court= new Court(); " inside do block as first statement.

Comment: @Khodayar why don't you guys use [Simple]CursorAdapter when dealing with sqlite db? it is a big mystery seeing people making the same error again and again... see that guy positing one hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337335/delete-entry-from-sqlite-data-base-in-android-application-where-to-get-the-that#31337878